# .htaccess - конфликт переадресаций: https и поддомены

Tags: .htaccess, сервер, url, веб-сервер, поддомены

В .htaccess прописана и хорошо работает инструкция переадресации всех вариантов написания адреса сайта на основной домен `https://mysite.ru`.:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://mysite.ru/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Я хотел бы также реализовать  переадресацию субдоменов в соответствующую папку. Инструкция хорошо работает на обычных http-доменах:

```
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_VHOST} ^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mysite\.ru$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) %1/$1 [L,E=VHOST:1]
```

Однако в моем случае две переадресации, естественно, вступают в конфликт и субдомены не работают. Не могу никак сообразить как их объединить воедино - (перестановка "до" или "после", конечно,  не дает результата). Чтобы например адреса: `https://sub.mysite.ru`, `http://sub.mysite.ru`, `www.sub.mysite.ru` перереадресовывались как положено на `https://mysite.ru/sub`.

Следующая инструкция **не работает**:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /

# переадресация субдоменов
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_VHOST} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mysite\.ru$
RewriteRule ^(.*) %1/$1 [L,E=VHOST:1]

# переадресация на https:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://mysite.ru/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,NS]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден, буду рад, если пригодится кому-то еще:
переадресация `http:`, `www` и без указания протокола на `https:`
Только после этого проверяются и переадресовываются поддомены:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_VHOST} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)\.mysite\.ru$
RewriteRule ^(.*) %2/$1 [L,E=VHOST:1]
```

Протестировано на реально действующем сайте.